# store comma separated key=value pair in a string to $key, $value variable in shell

Tags: bash, dictionary

In my bash shell script I have a comma separated key,value pairs in a form of single string. How to parse and store each key and value in separate variables.
For example,
`string1="key1=value1,key2=value2"`
I want to convert this to,
`echo 'key1 = value1' >> key1.txt
echo 'key2 = value2' >> key2.txt`
 The number of key,value pairs in string1 will be dynamic. How to do this in shell script?
I have used cut to get the key and value. But I am not sure how loop that over numbers of pairs ina string.

```
string1='key1=value1'
KEY=$(echo $string1 | cut -f1 -d=)
VALUE=$(echo $string1 | cut -f2 -d=)
```

Comment: please specify which shell; there are many, very different from each other. Also, always try to include a snippet of code with what you've tried o far.

Comment: Add code I had used. BTW I am using bash shell

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

string1="key1=value1,key2=value2"

while read -d, -r pair; do
  IFS='=' read -r key val <<<"$pair"
  echo "$key = $val"
done <<<"$string1,"
```

<sup>Note the trailing `,` in `"$string1,"`, which ensures that `read` also enters the `while` loop body with the *last* `,`-separated token.</sup>

yields:

```
key1 = value1
key2 = value2
```

---

To write the key-value pairs to sequentially numbered files (`key<n>.txt`, starting with `1`):

```
#!/bin/bash

string1="key1=value1,key2=value2"

i=0
while read -d, -r pair; do
  IFS='=' read -r key val <<<"$pair"
  echo "$key = $val" > "key$((++i)).txt"
done <<<"$string1,"
```

Comment: @Naresh, in bash >= 4, you can also load the values into an *associative array* if you need to make use of the key/value pairs later in your code (e.g. `declare -A pairs`, then within the loop you could simply do `pairs[$key]="$val"` to build the `pairs` array)

Answer (score -2):

Assuming that you're talking about bash, something like this can work:

```
#!/bin/bash

string1="key1=value1,key2=value2"
OIFS="$IFS"
IFS=","

for pair in ${string1}
do
        declare $pair
done

IFS="$OIFS"

echo $key1
echo $key2
```

Comment: Thanks Davide for your reply. In my logic, I wont be knowing the contents of string itself. It will be dynamic. In that case how can I parse my string. I have updated the question as per you asked.

Comment: Relying on unquoted expansions is really unfortunate. Not only does this eliminating distinctions between characters in IFS (emitting tabs as spaces, or groups of spaces as single spaces, when IFS is at its default value), it also causes globs to be expanded (so a line containing only a `*` would have an action entirely dependent on local filenames).

Comment: Related: [Don't Read Lines With `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor), [BashPitfalls #14](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo)